NsdManager resolveService is deprecated
In my Android application, I employ the NsdManager to discover nearby services and establish connections with them. However, when utilizing an Android 13 device, I encounter a recurring issue during the service resolution process with resolveService. Specifically, there are instances where not all the required host addresses are obtained at the time of invocation. Strikingly, this problem isn't consistently reproducible (sometimes I receive only an ipv6 address, other times both an ipv4 and an ipv6 adddress).
To address this challenge, I've opted to utilize the registerServiceInfoCallback method on Android 14 and above. This approach allows me to receive updates whenever a new host address is discovered, ensuring a more reliable service resolution process. Unfortunately, due to compatibility constraints, this method cannot be employed on devices with an API level lower than 34.
